# Use Quota in Ubuntu 16.04 in normal way

Tags: linux, ftp, kernel, ubuntu-16.04, quota

I was trying to setup quota for my ftp users on fresh Ubuntu 16.04.
I was using this [flow](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-user-and-group-quotas)

But at the end came to flowing error, after running "quotaon /" i got error

> quotaon: using //aquota.user on /dev/vda1 [/]: No such process
>
> quotaon: Quota format not supported in kernel.

I found alternative tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/enable-quota-ubuntu-16-04-error) which uses

```
apt-get -y install linux-image-generic
apt-get -y install linux-headers-generic
apt-get -y install linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
```

**kernel overwriting method** which i think is not so good approach.

I wondered if there is not present some alternative to "quotaon" ? as it is removed from kernel then there should be some normal **alternative** functionality to it ? or some other way to enable quotaon without re installation  of "linux-image-generic ..." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the Virtual kernel inside a virtual machine, then this is
a known
[bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/761809)
that can be fixed by installing the package `linux-image-extra-virtual`.

Otherwise, a better tutorial on enabling quota is found in the Stack Overflow post
[Ubuntu quota format not supported in kernel](https://serverfault.com/questions/843994/ubuntu-quota-format-not-supported-in-kernel),
which is more comprehensive than the one you found.

This does not involve *modifying* the Linux kernel, but it only causes
the quota modules to start with the boot, so that the quota command is enabled.
By default these kernel modules are not enabled, so that quota is unavailable.

For completeness, here is the relevant part of the answer:

> We can install the full missing linux-generic package:
>
> ```
> apt-get -y install linux-generic
> ```
>
> Or only the extras packages (I prefer this):
>
> ```
> apt-get -y install linux-image-generic
> apt-get -y install linux-headers-generic
> apt-get -y install linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
> ```
>
> We need add the quota modules to start with boot:
>
> ```
> echo quota_v1 >> /etc/modules
> echo quota_v2 >> /etc/modules
>
> reboot
> ```
>
> Check if it's working:
>
> ```
> sudo -s
> cat /proc/modules | grep -i quota
>
> quota_v1 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc037c000
> quota_v2 16384 2 - Live 0xffffffffc0377000
> quota_tree 20480 1 quota_v2, Live 0xffffffffc0250000
>
> quotaon -pa
>
> group quota on / (/dev/sda1) is on
> user quota on / (/dev/sda1) is on
> ```
>
> Both quotas are activated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that This method `This does not involve modifying the Linux kernel`